# Accessing Images in Static Folder

Tags: python, django, image, static

I've placed some images in /static/some_directory and Django cannot find them. But when the same images are placed in /static/images, Django is able to find them. My settings.py has the following:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Added to make "static" directory path relative to BASE_DIR
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), )
```

What do I need to add to make this work? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post the template code you are having problems with please.

Comment: Open up the chrome dev tools, network tab, hit the all( it defaults to XHR) reload and look at the problem images

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: Try to use this file structure for static files:
`my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg`
and if you want to separate images in image directory:
`my_app/static/my_app/images/example.jpg`